# Displaying panel using ajax in apache wicket

Tags: java, ajax, wicket

I am learning wicket framework and while working with ajax I tried one example in which I want to display a panel with selected radio button's company name. But while doing this I am getting some error. Here I mentioned all details from my coding:

Test.java

```
public class Test extends WebPage {

private static final List<String> companies = Arrays.asList(new String[] {"Google","Microsoft","Yahoo"});
private ArrayList<String> compSelected = new ArrayList<String>();
private Panel panel;
public Test(final PageParameters parameters) {
    final RadioChoice<String> companyList = 
                new RadioChoice<String>("companyNames",new Model(compSelected),companies);

    companyList.add(new AjaxFormChoiceComponentUpdatingBehavior() {

        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            if("Google".equals(companyList.getModelObject())){
                panel = new Panel1("panel1","Google");
            }
            else if("Microsoft".equals(companyList.getModelObject())){
                panel = new Panel1("panel1","Microsoft");
            }
            else{
                panel = new Panel1("panel1","Yahoo");
            }
            panel.setOutputMarkupId(true);
            target.addComponent(panel);
        }});
    Form<?> form = new Form<Void>("form");
    add(form);
    form.add(companyList);
    form.add(panel);
    this.add(form);
}
}
```

Test.html

```
<form wicket:id="form">
    <label><b>Company List:</b></label><br>
    <span wicket:id="companyNames">radio button list will goes here</span><br>
    <span wicket:id = "panel1" class="panel">panel goes here</span>
</form>
```

Panel1.java

```
 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
 public class Panel1 extends Panel{

     public Panel1(String id,String cName) {
         super(id);
         add(new Label("msg", "selected company is:"+ cName));
     }
 }
```

Panel1.html

```
<body>
    <wicket:panel>
        <span wicket:id="msg">message goes here</span>
    </wicket:panel>
</body>
```

> WicketMessage: Can't instantiate page using constructor public demo.wicket.ajax.Test(org.apache.wicket.PageParameters) and argument Root cause:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument child may not be null     at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.add(MarkupContainer.java:131)     at demo.wicket.ajax.Test.(Test.java:46)     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.createPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:188)     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:65)     at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.newPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:299)     at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.getPage(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:321)     at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.processEvents(BookmarkablePageRequestTarget.java:234)     at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92)     at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250)     at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329)     at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1428)     at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545)     at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:468)     at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:301)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)     at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)     at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

I am not sure what I did wrong here. can someone please help me to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `form.add(panel);`. `panel` is null at that time. You initialize it in `#onUpdate()` but it is executed only after a click(?) on the radio buttons.

Solution: 
Change `panel` type to `WebMarkupContainer` and initialize it in the page's constructor. Call `panel.setOutputMarkupId(true)` also in the constructor so the `<span wicket:id="panel1"...>` has an `id` in the rendered HTML and being able to be referenced later with JS to replace/update it. In `#onUpdate()` use something like `panel = panel.replaceWith(new Panel1(panel.getId(), choice.getModelObject())); target.add(panel);`

Comment: panel = panel.replaceWith(new Panel1(panel.getId(), choice.getModelObject())); This line giving an error "can not convert from void to WebMarkupContainer"

Comment: OK. The make it `private MarkupContainer panel1 = new WebMackupContainer("someId')`